# If span class "markup_zzz" comes right after span class "markup_zz" add class

Tags: jquery, css

I can't figure out how to target a span class only if it's followed by another specific one.

For example:

```
<span class="markup_z">Item one</span>
<span class="markup_zz">Item two</span>
<span class="markup_xx">Item three</span>
<span class="markup_zzz">Item four</span>
```

I would like to do something like if markup_zz is followed by markup_zzz add class "open" to markup_zz item number three in the example above.

Think of markup_zz as the parent and markup_zzz as child. If there is a child add class open to parent.

This is what I have so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".markup_z:not(:last-child):has(+ .markup_zz)")
.addClass("open");
});
```

But that only works for the first level.

I can't change the spans so it has to be done in some other way.

Comment: What do you mean by "only works for the first level"? And in your span example, wouldn't nothing be done since markup_xx falles between markup_zz and markup_zzz?

Comment: In this scenario you seem to be mis-using css classes?  Which might be contributing to your difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct function/selector to achieve what you are asking for.
You need to search - for each item next to the specific one - if its class matches the requirements.

[.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) are probably what you are looking for.

Here's a little snipet. Click the spans to activate the lookup for each element.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function() {
        
        // get the classes of the span
        var $classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
        var found = false;
        
        // foreach class
        for (var i = 0; i < $classes.length && ! found; ++i) {
            var current_class = $classes[i];
            if (current_class !== 'clickable') {    // (avoid checking 'clickable')
                
                // add the last letter of the class
                var target_class = current_class + current_class[current_class.length - 1];
                
                // get sibling elements after the clicked one
                var $elems = $(this).nextAll();
                
                // search foreach elem after the clicked one if any of the
                // classes of that element are the target_class
                for (var j = 0; j < $elems.length && ! found; ++j) {
                    var elem = $elems[j];
                    if ($(elem).hasClass(target_class))
                        found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // if the clicked element matches our requirements
        if (found) {
            /*
             * ... do something
             * 
             */
            $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style='margin-bottom:50px;'>
    <span class="clickable markup_a">one</span>
    <span class="clickable markup_aa">two</span>
    <span class="clickable markup_bb">three</span>
    <span class="clickable markup_aaa">four</span>
</div>
```

**------------------ EDIT ------------------**

[Execute a function when the document is ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Once you know how to automatically execute a function, use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate over elements or arrays.

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6q0ne9h/1/).

Comment: Very clever and it might work if I could trigger it onload without a click. I haven't been able to figure that out, newbie and all but I'm googling all I can to learn!

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly when I test it but not in my code. Must be some kind of conflict, gets message to stop script or debug. Looking for the problem now. Frustrating but educational I guess.

Comment: You are welcome. Provide your code via jsFiddle if you need some help debugging and I'll be glad to help.